# Django - migrate database from sqlite to mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to migrate my sqlite database to mysql. I used dumdata/loaddata commands:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
```

next changed my settings.py to

```
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testowa',
        'USER': 'testowy',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and run `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`

I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'testowa.constance_config' doesn't exist")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you run `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes. I did it before datadump and after that. After that I get the same error.

Comment: Did the migration succeed?

Comment: No it didn't. I think it is django-constance fault. It uses its own database. I'll try to solve it but for this time I don't have any ideas.

Comment: The problem _might_ be caused by the checks in core/checks/registry.py . For me it helped to uncomment and skip the checks, then the migration was performed correctly. I found this by running the migration in Debug from PyCharm. If you choose to comment the checks, turn 'm back on afterwards :)

Comment: I found that file (registry.py) but i don't know what should I comment/uncomment. By the way It is strange that I get the same error when I try any of python mange.py commands (runserver for example).

Answer (score 0):

Django need

1) use migrate command to the new database (if you are using authrouter, specify the database with:

> python manange.py migrate --database=yourdatabasename

2) dumpdata with a logic order (example if in table1 you have a foreing key to table2, table2 must be imported before the table1)

3) To create the logic order just dump the single model with

> ./manage.py dumpdata myapp1.fist_model myapp1.second_model > ordered_file.json

4) After that load the data